# Grouper and axis must be of same length

Tags: group-by, compiler-errors

I want to group a data according to day and month but the error shows "grouper and axis must be same length. what can I do?

```
df2['Date'] = df2['Date'].astype(str)
times1= pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['Date'])
df2 = df2[~(df2['Date'].str.endswith(r'02-29'))]
df2 = df2.groupby(by=[times1.month,times1.day])
```